# iPhone 7 - problems with pop-up websites

Tags: iphone

I’ve had a problem with websites popping up in place of websites I’m trying to access. Can you block websites with suffixes such as .top and .club? I’ve been able to block individual websites but silmilar sites keep popping up with the common denominator being those two suffixes.

Answer (score 1):

Most ad blocker extensions for iOS allow you to add custom rules, which should allow you to block whole domains as well. I use [1Blocker](https://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/1blocker/id1025729002?mt=8), there are probably others with similar features.